# MySQL: OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' Breaking INTO OUTFILE Variable Name

Tags: mysql, macos, csv, into-outfile

I've been attempting to make a csv export properly into my test folder with a variable file name -- I'm getting close but I think I've got it down to one problem before it works. Here's the code so far:

```
SET @q1 := CONCAT(
"SELECT *
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/SQLOut/test"
, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d')
,".csv'"
, "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");

PREPARE s1 FROM @q1;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

As you can see, I have to use `prepared statements` in order to get the filename to include today's date. That part works -- but if I want to make it a csv, I need to include the 'fields terminated' stuff afterwards, which is what I think is breaking it.

I believe this would function as intended if the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` didn't contain `"` -- the double quotes after it are closing my original `"` after `CONCAT(` and the final line of `'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");` is getting cut off and MySQL is getting confused.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SET @`qry` := CONCAT('
   SELECT *
   FROM `table`
   INTO OUTFILE \'/SQLOut/test', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), '.csv\'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
   LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'
');

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DROP PREPARE `stmt`;
```

Comment: I think this did it, thank you! Would you mind explaining a bit of what you did so I understand? Looks like the \s had a lot to do with it.

Comment: Because if I add any columns headers or conditions where I need to use a single quote now then it breaks just like it did before

Comment: @Ryan: Check [10.1.1 String Literals :: Table 10.1 Special Character Escape Sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences).